# How to convert from float to bigDecimal in java?

Tags: java, floating-point, bigdecimal

How to convert from float to bigDecimal  in java?

Answer (score 75):

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(Float.toString(123.4f));
```

From the [javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), the string constructor is generally the preferred way to convert a `float` into a BigDecimal, as it doesn't suffer from the unpredictability of the `BigDecimal(double)` constructor.

Quote from the docs:

> *Note: For values other float and double  NaN and ±Infinity, this constructor is compatible with the values returned by Float.toString(float) and Double.toString(double). **This is generally the preferred way to convert a float or double into a BigDecimal**, as it doesn't suffer from the unpredictability of the BigDecimal(double) constructor.*

Comment: But converting a `float` to a String explicitly doesn't help you solve the unpredictability automatically - you need to take care to format the value correctly (rounding etc.).

Comment: How to convert and format 9.991f to 910 and 9.99f to 9.99?

Comment: See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#toString-float-

Answer (score 29):

```
float f = 45.6f;
BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(f);
```

Quote from documentations:

> Note: This is generally the preferred way to convert a double (or
>   float) into a BigDecimal, as the value returned is equal to that
>   resulting from constructing a BigDecimal from the result of using
>   Double.toString(double).

Reference: [BigDecimal (Java Platform SE 6)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf%28double%29)

Comment: `Double.toString(float)` produces a different result than `Float.toString(float)`.

Comment: `BigDecimal.valueOf( 1.1f )`  results in `1.100000023841858`

Comment: WARNING = that `45.6f` will become `45.599998474121094` in `BigDecimal`. See another answer if you don't want this.

Answer (score 9):

For a precision of 3 digits after the decimal point:

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(f,
        new MathContext(3, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN));
```

Comment: How to convert and format 9.991f to 910 and 9.99f to 9.99?

Comment: @Jobin I don't get your question. Why would 9.991f be converted to 910? Did you mean 10 instead of 910? in that case, you would need `new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.UP)` or `new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.CEILING)` depending on how you want to deal with the negative numbers.

Answer (score 3):

This is upto my knowledge :

```
   public static BigDecimal floatToBigDecimal(Float a){


    if(a == null || a.isInfinite() || a.isNaN()){
        return BigDecimal.ZERO;
    }
    try{
        return BigDecimal.valueOf(a);

    }catch(Exception e){
        return BigDecimal.ZERO;
    }

}
```

> *Note:This is generally the preferred way to convert a double (or float) into a BigDecimal, as the value returned is equal to that resulting from constructing a BigDecimal from the result of using Double.toString(double).

public static BigDecimal valueOf(double val)

**Parameters**:
    val - double to convert to a BigDecimal.
**Returns**:
    a BigDecimal whose value is equal to or approximately equal to the value of val.
**Throws:**
    ***NumberFormatException*** - if val is infinite or NaN.
**Since:**
    1.5

I have checked whether Infinite or Not a Number, so that there is less chances of NumberFormatException