# How to display BigDecimal value in a human readable format?

Tags: java

Suppose we have a BigDecimal variable setted up like this, and we can't change the way of it's creation:

```
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(6.0053);
```

So we'll see the following 'pretty' value after an output:

```
System.out.println(num);   //0053000000000000824229573481716215610504150390625
```

The only way I've found to resolve this problem was using BigDecimal.valueOf():

```
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(num.doubleValue()));   //6.0053
```

But is there a more simple solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use the `new BigDecimal(double)` constructor - it creates unprecise values: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829029/how-to-convert-from-float-to-bigdecimal-in-java

Comment: Well the underlying problem is with the value, which doesn't represent what you want it to represent. You say you can't change the way it's created, but you should really focus on that, as that's where the problem started. Anything else is just papering over the cracks.

Comment: @Natix: No, it creates perfectly precise values - just not the values you might expect. I disagree with the documentation about "unpredictability" here - the result is predictable, but you need to understand what's going on first.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I know that the problem is with creation, and was only interested in some quick and dirty workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `java.text.DecimalFormat` to format the numbers.

```
NumberFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.####");
System.out.println(format.format(num));
```

The format options can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Comment: I bet it wouldn't be simpler than BigDecimal.valueOf(num.doubleValue()). I was wondering are there any very simple solutions?

Comment: @XpressOneUp No indeed, and this poster hasn't claimed otherwise, but it will also provide a specific number of decimal places, and avoid scientific notation, and various other things you probably need but may not know about yet. Your choice.

Answer (score 2):

```
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(6.0053);
DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("0.0000");
System.out.println(df.format(num));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("###,##0.00").format(myBigDecimalVariable));
```

Comment: BigDecimals are Numbers and thus can be passed to the DecimalFormat, no need to convert them to double first (loss of precision and smaller number range).

Comment: That's right, didn't know that... Will edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.format` with the "`g`" formatting type. It allows you to control how many digits you want, etc. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for all formatting options.

```
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(6.0053);
String formated = String.format("%6.5g", num);
System.out.println(formated);
```

(Result : `6.0053`)