# Full precision numbers in python and JSON library

Tags: python, json, floating-point, precision

Having a small issue with the code below with a recursive error:

100s errors printed ending in this:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

As you can see below my code is not recursive so something is happening with the DecimalEncoder.

Code

```
import json
import decimal      # tell json to leave my float values alone

class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            return decimal.Decimal(o)
            #return str(o)
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)

class JSONUtils:
    def __init__( self, response ):
        self.response = response
        self.jsonData = None
        self.LoadData( )

        print 'jsonData: ' + json.dumps( self.jsonData, cls=DecimalEncoder, indent=2 )

    def LoadData ( self ):
        if ( self.jsonData == None ):
            if ( type( self.response ) == str or type( self.response ) == unicode ):
                #self.jsonData = json.loads(self.response )
                self.jsonData = json.loads(self.response, parse_float=decimal.Decimal )

    def GetJSONChunk( self, path ):
        returnValue = ''
        curPath     = ''
        try:
            if ( type( path ) == str ):
                returnValue = self.jsonData[path]
            elif (type( path ) == list):
                temp = ''
                firstTime = True
                for curPath in path:
                    if firstTime == True:
                        temp = self.jsonData[curPath]
                        firstTime = False
                    else:
                        temp = temp[curPath]
                returnValue = temp
            else:
                print 'Unknown type in GetJSONChunk: ' + unicode( type( path ))
        except KeyError as err:
            ti.DBG_OUT( 'JSON chunk doesn\'t have value: ' + unicode( path ))
            returnValue = self.kNoNode
        except IndexError as err:
            ti.DBG_OUT( 'Index does not exist: ' + unicode( curPath ))
            returnValue = self.kInvalidIndex

        return returnValue

myJSON = JSONUtils( unicode('{ "fldName":4.9497474683058327445566778899001122334455667788990011 }' ))
value =  str( myJSON.GetJSONChunk ( 'fldName' ))
print str( type( value ))
print value
```

If I swap return decimal.Decimal(0) for a string.  It gets rid of the error BUT the value as you can see, is returned as a string.

```
#return decimal.Decimal(o)
return str(o)
```

This output is close but I need a double at the type:

```
jsonData: {
  "fldName": "4.9497474683058327445566778899001122334455667788990011"
}
<type 'str'>
4.9497474683058327445566778899001122334455667788990011
```

If I swap these lines you can see the original issue which looses precision.

```
#self.jsonData = json.loads(self.response )
self.jsonData = json.loads(self.response, parse_float=decimal.Decimal )
```

Comment: Python's `json` module doesn't support this. Just encode the `Decimal` as a string, and call `Decimal` on the string on the other end.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm writing a testing application which tests values being returned back from the database.  I can't convert all strings to doubles since some strings are strings and others are numbers.  Also it won't be a good answer to our users once we give them the changes we are planning.  They would have to pass around the field type which is a bit heavy.

Comment: @Advait can you take a look at this one?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting into this recursion error because the `default` method in `DecimalEncoder` is returning the same type it's supposed to handle, instead of turning it in a serializable type.

If you debug your code in a debugger, you'll be able to see that in a given moment, a internal call of `JSONEncoder` is trying to convert the value to one of the default serializable types, and since no one matches, it calls the fallback, which is the `default` method in `DecimalEncoder` class.

This is why the statement `return str(o)` works. It's returning a different type than `Decimal` which is a serializable one.

I recommend you to follow the  user2357112's advice, and consider to encode the `Decimal` as a string, and convert it back on the other end.

The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38357877/7254201 points out some reasons to use string instead of `Decimal` in JSON.

### Update #1

Following below my suggestion about how to convert the decimal into a string so that you can get the original value later.

Use the `DecimalEncoder` to turn the decimal value in a new `dict` where there is a key called `value` a another called `type`, so you put both as string. Of course there will be some further work when deserializing the value.

```
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            return {
                'value': str(o),
                'type': str(type(o).__name__) # you can use another code to provide the type.
            }
            #return str(o)
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)
```

Following this strategy, the output of your code will looks like below:

```
jsonData: {
  "fldName": {
    "type": "decimal", 
    "value": "4.9497474683058327445566778899001122334455667788990011"
  }
}
```

As I see it, this problem is all about keeping the value and its type when serializing it. In those cases I try, when it's possible, to separate the data and its 'meta' information.

---

### Update #2

**How to decode it**

Now, you have your object like:

```
  "fldName": {
    "type": "decimal", 
    "value": "4.9497474683058327445566778899001122334455667788990011"
  }
```

You may want to deserialize it as:

```
  {
    "fldName": Decimal('4.9497474683058327445566778899001122334455667788990011')
  }
```

So, you can do something based on this gist code: https://gist.github.com/simonw/7000493

I change the gist code a little bit to the below:

```
class DecimalDecoder(json.JSONDecoder):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        json.JSONDecoder.__init__(self, object_hook=self.object_hook, *args, **kwargs)

    def object_hook(self, obj):
        if 'type' not in obj:
            return obj

        obj_type = obj['type']
        if obj_type == 'decimal':
            return decimal.Decimal(obj.get('value'))
        return obj
```

My test code was:

```
    jsonData = json.dumps( self.jsonData, cls=DecimalEncoder, indent=2 )
    print 'jsonData: ' + jsonData
    newObj = json.loads(jsonData, cls=DecimalDecoder)
    print 'newObj: ' + str(newObj)
```

The output was:

```
jsonData: {
  "fldName": {
    "type": "decimal", 
    "value": "4.9497474683058327445566778899001122334455667788990011"
  }
}
newObj: {u'fldName': Decimal('4.9497474683058327445566778899001122334455667788990011')}
```

Comment: That seams to indicate that I could make up a type, tell JSON to handle float as that made up type and then have the DecimalEncoder recognize that type and move it to decimal.  I have no idea what made up type would work.  This seams reasonable to try.  What do you think?  I understand the article that you pointed to basically states that it is safer to store the value as a string.

Comment: Please read my answer's updates. Hopefully it can give you some ideas.

Comment: Sorry I missed your updates... Yes I had found the answer on my own.  Very close to your answer and it is giving me the correct answer and type.  Making my testing much easier.  TY a bunch it's been fun!!