# Formating decimal JsonResult ASP MVC 5

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

I'm working with ASP MVC 5 and [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) plugin and I'm having some problems formating my decimals.

I need to format numbers with dot as thousand separator and comma as decimal separator.

I'm trying to do it with `DisplayFormat`, but since i'm returning the data as Json, it just not applying

This is a little example of my problem

```
public class MyClass
{
   [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.##}")]
   decimal MyDecimal {get;set;}
}
```

In the controller

```
public JsonResult LoadDataTables()
{    
    using(var db = new ExampleContext())
    {
        var data = db.MyRepository.Select(x => new MyClass
        {
            MyDecimal = x.mydecimal
        }).ToList();
        //i'm ignoring a lot of processing to create a short snippet
        return Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = data });
    }
}
```

Then, in the front end, the json arrives with comma for thousands and dot for decimal separation

How can i deal with it? Some way to apply `CultureInfo` or manually set the conversion?

Edit: In my view, this is how i'm loading the data

```
var table = $('#myTabla').DataTable({
                    processing: true,
                    serverSide: true,
                    filter: true,
                    orderMulti: false,
                    paging: true,
                    pageLength: 10,
                    ajax: {
                        "url": '@Url.Action("LoadDataTables")',
                        "type": "POST",
                        "datatype": "json",
                    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show your code in View, my friend?

Comment: Here is the documentation for ToString() output format : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings . You can apply CultureInfo for output.

Comment: @Tomato32 Addeded how i load the data, my view is only one table and that script basically

Comment: @Shim-Sao the problem is where must i apply that? the `DisplayFormat` annotation never happen

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal your JSON is just fine. Using dots *is* the defacto standard for numbers in JSON. It's you *DataTable* configuration that should specify how that decimal field gets displayed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that was my idea, but DataTables language settings (specify thousand and decimal) didn't work when you use server side processing :s

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal: Your problem is solved? :))

Comment: @Tomato32 I opted to convert decimals to string, at least for now, I did not answer the question because I think it is not a real solution

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal: Sorry for late response. There is a solution to this. If you need, I can post a sample :))

Comment: @Tomato32 thanks! post it please :P

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal: I posted it. Hope to help, my friend :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Number helper for this. You can visit this link to refer more: https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers#Number-helper

Here is a sample. Hope to help, my friend :))

//Code in Controller

```
public class Test
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Currency  { get; set; }
    }

private List<Test> Data()
        {
            var data = new List<Test>
            {
                new Test{ Id = 1, Name = "A1", Currency = 1000000.00M},
                new Test{ Id = 2, Name = "A2", Currency= 50000000.12M},
                new Test{ Id = 3, Name = "A3", Currency = 3000000.45M},
                new Test{ Id = 4, Name = "A4", Currency = 20000}
            };
            return data;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult LoadDataTables()
        {
            var data = Data();
            var recordsTotal = Data().Count;
            var recordsFiltered = Data().Count();
            string draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw")[0];
            return Json(new { draw = Convert.ToInt32(draw), recordsTotal = recordsTotal, recordsFiltered = recordsFiltered, data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

//View

```
<table id="myTable" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td >Id</td>
            <td >Name</td>
            <td>Currency</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>

    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
                    processing: true,
                    serverSide: true,
                    filter: true,
                    orderMulti: false,
                    paging: true,
                    pageLength: 10,
                    ajax: {
                            "url": '@Url.Action("LoadDataTables", "Home")',
                            "type": "POST",
                            "datatype": "json",
                    },
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "data": "Id"
                        }, {
                            "data": "Name"
                        }, {
                            "data": "Currency",
                            render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number('.', ',', 2, '')
                        }
                    ]
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set custom culture:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo customCulture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer! i try it, but the result is the same :(

Comment: Have you removed the attribute [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.##}")]?

Comment: Yes i'm, i already had the culture configured, my problem is, for some reason its not get applyed to the Json conversion

Comment: Read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709595/why-would-you-use-a-string-in-json-to-represent-a-decimal-number

Answer (score 1):

1 - You can do it in another way like this :

```
public class MyClass
{
   MyNumber MyDecimal {get;set;}
}

struct MyNumber
{
    decimal Value {get;set;}

    ToString()
    {
        // Adapt number Format and CultureInfo as wanted
        return value.ToString("0:0.##", MyCultureInfo);
    }
}
```

uses :

decimal d = MyNumber.Value

string s = (string)MyNumber; or MyNumber.ToString();

2 - Or on client side :

```
// Invert . and ,
// 1.22222.5689,56
// to 1,22222,5689.56
String.prototype.formatNumber = function(number)
{
    return number.replace(',', ';').replace('.', ',').replace(';', '.');
}
```

3 - My best choice to manipulate JSon in C# is : https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

You can serialize and deserialize json and creating custom conversion.