# Decimal formatting issue in net.sf.json Object

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

We are using compile `net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.4:jdk15`

```
String requestBody =     {"resconfirmsvid":28,"reservationno":"H0028W090718","component":"Hotel","partnerid":2,"total":169002.15,"internalnote":"","currencycode":"USD","history":[{"id":"0","payment_type":"Payment","payment_method":"Cash","date":"2019-10-30","refnumber":"012525TRTY","amount":160000,"currency":"USD","component":"Hotel","resconfirmsvid":28}]}

requestBody = URLDecoder.decode(requestBody, "UTF-8");
JSONObject request = JSONObject.fromObject(requestBody);
```

Then request object as follows,

```
request = {"resconfirmsvid":28,"reservationno":"H0028W090718","component":"Hotel","partnerid":2,"total":169002.16,"internalnote":"","currencycode":"USD","history":[{"id":"0","payment_type":"Payment","payment_method":"Cash","date":"2019-10-30","refnumber":"012525TRTY","amount":160000,"currency":"USD","component":"Hotel","resconfirmsvid":28}]}
```

After convert json string into json object using fromObject **"total"** value changed to  **169002.16** from **169002.15**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a same issue, when i used net.sf.json-lib for coverting json string into Json object.once i used the below gradle version
`compile 'net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.3:jdk15'`
issue was fixed sucessfully.

Comment: When you downgrade the jar it will effected following issue fixes and new enhancement. Please consider this before downgrade the jar. http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/changes-report.html#a2.4

Answer (score 1):

JSON does not specify a precision for decimal numbers.  That's why it is recommended to use strings for decimal numbers instead.

Source: [Why would you use a string in JSON to represent a decimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709595/why-would-you-use-a-string-in-json-to-represent-a-decimal-number) - dthorpe