# how to change the case of properties with MassTransit

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, masstransit

How to change the formatting of a property from camelCase to PascalCase.

Is there any standardized way to format? some middleware? I didn't find anything in the documentation.

And one more question. Why does masstransit's json converter convert decimal to string?

Examplo:
My class:

```
public class Block
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int AccountValue { get; set; }
}
```

currently generated message:

```
{
  "name": 3,
  "age": 34,
  "accountValue": "3430.64"
}
```

expected message:

```
{
  "Name": 3,
  "Age": 34,
  "AccountValue": 3430.64
}
```

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the JSON serializer setting, you can call:

`cfg.ConfigureJsonSerializer(x => ...)`

When configuring the bus.

MassTransit converts `decimal` to a string because *decimal* types are more precise than JSON float types. If you want it to not be a string, use a double instead of a decimal.

For relevant comments, [look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709595/why-would-you-use-a-string-in-json-to-represent-a-decimal-number) as to why decimals should not be passed as JSON floats.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Patterson. You helped me a lot