# How can I JSON encode BigDecimal and BigInteger in Kotlinx Serialization without losing precision?

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization, bigdecimal, kotlinx.serialization

I'm using Kotlin/JVM 1.8.0 and Kotlinx Serialization 1.4.1.

I need to encode a `java.math.BigDecimal` and `java.math.BigInteger` to JSON.

I'm using `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger` because the values I want to encode can be larger than a `Double` can hold, and also I want to avoid [errors with floating-point precision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/4161471). I don't want to encode the numbers as strings because JSON is read by other programs, so it needs to be correct.

The JSON spec places [no restriction on the length of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35709595/4161471), so it should be possible.

When I try and use `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger` directly, I get an error

```kotlin
import java.math.*
import kotlinx.serialization.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.*

@Serializable
data class FooNumbers(
  val decimal: BigDecimal,
  val integer: BigInteger,
)
```

```
Serializer has not been found for type 'BigDecimal'. To use context serializer as fallback, explicitly annotate type or property with @Contextual
Serializer has not been found for type 'BigInteger'. To use context serializer as fallback, explicitly annotate type or property with @Contextual
```

I tried creating custom serializers for `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger` ([and `typealias`es for convenience](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/v1.5.0-RC/docs/serializers.md#specifying-serializer-globally-using-typealias)), but because these use `toDouble()` and `toLong()` they lose precision!

```kotlin
typealias BigDecimalJson = @Serializable(with = BigDecimalSerializer::class) BigDecimal

private object BigDecimalSerializer : KSerializer<BigDecimal> {

  override val descriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("java.math.BigDecimal", PrimitiveKind.DOUBLE)

  override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): BigDecimal =
    decoder.decodeDouble().toBigDecimal()

  override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: BigDecimal) =
    encoder.encodeDouble(value.toDouble())
}

typealias BigIntegerJson = @Serializable(with = BigIntegerSerializer::class) BigInteger

private object BigIntegerSerializer : KSerializer<BigInteger> {

  override val descriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("java.math.BigInteger", PrimitiveKind.LONG)

  override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): BigInteger =
    decoder.decodeLong().toBigInteger()

  override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: BigInteger) =
    encoder.encodeLong(value.toLong())
}
```

When I encode and decode an example instance, a different result is returned.

```kotlin
import java.math.*
import kotlinx.serialization.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json

@Serializable
data class FooNumbers(
  val decimal: BigDecimalJson,
  val integer: BigIntegerJson,
)

fun main() {
  val fooDecimal = BigDecimal("0.1234567890123456789012345678901234567890")
  val fooInteger = BigInteger("9876543210987654321098765432109876543210")

  val fooNumbers = FooNumbers(fooDecimal, fooInteger)
  println("$fooNumbers")

  val encodedNumbers = Json.encodeToString(fooNumbers)
  println(encodedNumbers)

  val decodedFooNumbers = Json.decodeFromString<FooNumbers>(encodedNumbers)
  println("$decodedFooNumbers")

  require(decodedFooNumbers == fooNumbers)
}
```

The `require(...)` fails:

```
FooNumbers(decimal=0.1234567890123456789012345678901234567890, integer=9876543210987654321098765432109876543210)
{"decimal":0.12345678901234568,"integer":1086983617567424234}
FooNumbers(decimal=0.12345678901234568, integer=1086983617567424234)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed requirement.
    at MainKt.main(asd.kt:32)
    at MainKt.main(asd.kt)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Encoding raw JSON is possible in [Kotlinx Serialization 1.5.0](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/v1.5.0/CHANGELOG.md#json-unquoted-literals), which was released on 24th Feb 2023, and is experimental. It is not possible in earlier versions.

tl:dr: skip to 'Full example' at the bottom of this answer

#### Decoding using `JsonDecoder`

Note that it's only *encoding* that requires the workaround - decoding `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger` will work directly, so long as `JsonDecoder` is used!

```kotlin
private object BigDecimalSerializer : KSerializer<BigDecimal> {

  // ...

  override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): BigDecimal =
    when (decoder) {
      // must use decodeJsonElement() to get the value, and then convert it to a BigDecimal
      is JsonDecoder -> decoder.decodeJsonElement().jsonPrimitive.content.toBigDecimal()
      else -> decoder.decodeString().toBigDecimal()
    }
}
```

#### Encoding using `JsonUnquotedLiteral`

To encode, the new [`JsonUnquotedLiteral()`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/v1.5.0-RC/docs/json.md#encoding-literal-json-content-experimental) function must be used when encoding JSON.

```kotlin
private object BigDecimalSerializer : KSerializer<BigDecimal> {

  // ...

  override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: BigDecimal) =
    when (encoder) {
      // use JsonUnquotedLiteral() to encode the BigDecimal literally
      is JsonEncoder -> encoder.encodeJsonElement(JsonUnquotedLiteral(value.toPlainString()))
      else -> encoder.encodeString(value.toPlainString())
    }
}
```

#### Global config using typealias

Kotlinx Serialization uses [`typealias`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/type-aliases.html) to define [globally available serialization strategies](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/v1.5.0-RC/docs/serializers.md#specifying-serializer-globally-using-typealias). Let's do the same for `BigDecimal`

```kotlin
typealias BigDecimalJson = @Serializable(with = BigDecimalSerializer::class) BigDecimal
```

#### Example usage

After creating the serializers, the `typealias`es can be used in `FooNumber` to automatically use the `KSerializers`.

```kotlin
@Serializable
data class FooNumbers(
  val decimal: BigDecimalJson,
  val integer: BigIntegerJson,
)
```

The actual main function doesn't change - it's the same as before.

```kotlin
fun main() {
  val fooDecimal = BigDecimal("0.1234567890123456789012345678901234567890")
  val fooInteger = BigInteger("9876543210987654321098765432109876543210")

  val fooNumbers = FooNumbers(fooDecimal, fooInteger)
  println("$fooNumbers")

  val encodedNumbers = Json.encodeToString(fooNumbers)
  println(encodedNumbers)

  val decodedFooNumbers = Json.decodeFromString<FooNumbers>(encodedNumbers)
  println("$decodedFooNumbers")

  require(decodedFooNumbers == fooNumbers)
}
```

Now the `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger` can be encoded and decoded exactly, no loss of precision!

```
FooNumbers(decimal=0.1234567890123456789012345678901234567890, integer=9876543210987654321098765432109876543210)
{"decimal":0.1234567890123456789012345678901234567890,"integer":9876543210987654321098765432109876543210}
FooNumbers(decimal=0.1234567890123456789012345678901234567890, integer=9876543210987654321098765432109876543210)
```

#### Full example

Here's the full code:

```kotlin
import java.math.*
import kotlinx.serialization.*
import kotlinx.serialization.descriptors.*
import kotlinx.serialization.encoding.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.*

@Serializable
data class FooNumbers(
  val decimal: BigDecimalJson,
  val integer: BigIntegerJson,
)

fun main() {
  val fooDecimal = BigDecimal("0.1234567890123456789012345678901234567890")
  val fooInteger = BigInteger("9876543210987654321098765432109876543210")

  val fooNumbers = FooNumbers(fooDecimal, fooInteger)
  println("$fooNumbers")

  val encodedNumbers = Json.encodeToString(fooNumbers)
  println(encodedNumbers)

  val decodedFooNumbers = Json.decodeFromString<FooNumbers>(encodedNumbers)
  println("$decodedFooNumbers")

  require(decodedFooNumbers == fooNumbers)
}

typealias BigDecimalJson = @Serializable(with = BigDecimalSerializer::class) BigDecimal

@OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
private object BigDecimalSerializer : KSerializer<BigDecimal> {

  override val descriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("java.math.BigDecimal", PrimitiveKind.DOUBLE)

  /**
   * If decoding JSON uses [JsonDecoder.decodeJsonElement] to get the raw content,
   * otherwise decodes using [Decoder.decodeString].
   */
  override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): BigDecimal =
    when (decoder) {
      is JsonDecoder -> decoder.decodeJsonElement().jsonPrimitive.content.toBigDecimal()
      else           -> decoder.decodeString().toBigDecimal()
    }

  /**
   * If encoding JSON uses [JsonUnquotedLiteral] to encode the exact [BigDecimal] value.
   *
   * Otherwise, [value] is encoded using encodes using [Encoder.encodeString].
   */
  override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: BigDecimal) =
    when (encoder) {
      is JsonEncoder -> encoder.encodeJsonElement(JsonUnquotedLiteral(value.toPlainString()))
      else           -> encoder.encodeString(value.toPlainString())
    }
}

typealias BigIntegerJson = @Serializable(with = BigIntegerSerializer::class) BigInteger

@OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
private object BigIntegerSerializer : KSerializer<BigInteger> {

  override val descriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("java.math.BigInteger", PrimitiveKind.LONG)

  /**
   * If decoding JSON uses [JsonDecoder.decodeJsonElement] to get the raw content,
   * otherwise decodes using [Decoder.decodeString].
   */
  override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): BigInteger =
    when (decoder) {
      is JsonDecoder -> decoder.decodeJsonElement().jsonPrimitive.content.toBigInteger()
      else           -> decoder.decodeString().toBigInteger()
    }

  /**
   * If encoding JSON uses [JsonUnquotedLiteral] to encode the exact [BigInteger] value.
   *
   * Otherwise, [value] is encoded using encodes using [Encoder.encodeString].
   */
  override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: BigInteger) =
    when (encoder) {
      is JsonEncoder -> encoder.encodeJsonElement(JsonUnquotedLiteral(value.toString()))
      else           -> encoder.encodeString(value.toString())
    }
}
```